# In Elasticsearch, can I search for all documents with > *N* nested child documents?

Tags: elasticsearch

Let's say I've got a social network with the following mapping:

```
{
  “users” : {
    “properties” : {
      “username” : {“type” : “string”, "index": "not_analyzed”},
      “full_name” : {“type” : “string”},
      “friends” : {
        “type” : “nested”,
        “properties” : {
          “username” : {“type” : “string”, "index": "not_analyzed”},
          “date_friended” : {“type” : “date”},
        }
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Can I search for all users with > 5 friends?  As of right now, I'm maintaining a separate count of the children in the parent document.

Can I do this as a filtered query?  Do I need to use aggregations instead?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you solve this? looking for something very similar.

Comment: No.  I posted it on the elasticsearch forum as well.  No love.  Please let me know if you figure it out.